# Blank sides because of Spyropress's ___construct error

Tags: php, wordpress, construct

My Webspace-Provider just switched to php7 which leads to many blank sides on my webpage. Error when in Debug-Mode: "The Called Constructor Method For `WP_Widget` In `SpyroPress_Widget_Contact_Us` Is Deprecated Since Version 4.3.0! Use `__construct()`"
I can't even visit my wp-admin anymore.

I already tried many solution-methods, but none helped since i can't find any like that states "`$this->WP_Widget`". The errormsg says, that i should find it in my functions.php, line 3893, but in that specific line there is a commentary, nothing to change. Does anyone know where to find the lines which i have to update?
Even updating the theme from FTP didnt helped.

The Plugin / Framework in question is Spyropress.
Codefragment in Question (line 3893 and following):

```
 *
 * @param string $function The function that was called.
 * @param string $version  The version of WordPress that deprecated the argument used.
 * @param string $message  Optional. A message regarding the change. Default null.
 */
function _deprecated_argument( $function, $version, $message = null ) {

/**
 * Fires when a deprecated argument is called.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param string $function The function that was called.
 * @param string $message  A message regarding the change.
 * @param string $version  The version of WordPress that deprecated the argument used.
 */
do_action( 'deprecated_argument_run', $function, $message, $version );

/**
 * Filters whether to trigger an error for deprecated arguments.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param bool $trigger Whether to trigger the error for deprecated arguments. Default true.
 */
if ( WP_DEBUG && apply_filters( 'deprecated_argument_trigger_error', true ) ) {
    if ( function_exists( '__' ) ) {
        if ( ! is_null( $message ) ) {
            /* translators: 1: PHP function name, 2: version number, 3: optional message regarding the change */
            trigger_error( sprintf( __('%1$s was called with an argument that is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version %2$s! %3$s'), $function, $version, $message ) );
        } else {
            /* translators: 1: PHP function name, 2: version number */
            trigger_error( sprintf( __('%1$s was called with an argument that is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version %2$s with no alternative available.'), $function, $version ) );
        }
    } else {
        if ( ! is_null( $message ) ) {
            trigger_error( sprintf( '%1$s was called with an argument that is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version %2$s! %3$s', $function, $version, $message ) );
        } else {
            trigger_error( sprintf( '%1$s was called with an argument that is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version %2$s with no alternative available.', $function, $version ) );
        }
    }
}
}
/**
* Marks a deprecated action or filter hook as deprecated and throws a notice.
*
* Use the {@see 'deprecated_hook_run'} action to get the backtrace describing where
* the deprecated hook was called.
*
* Default behavior is to trigger a user error if `WP_DEBUG` is true.
*
* This function is called by the do_action_deprecated() and apply_filters_deprecated()
* functions, and so generally does not need to be called directly.
*
* @since 4.6.0
* @access private
*
* @param string $hook        The hook that was used.
* @param string $version     The version of WordPress that deprecated the hook.
* @param string $replacement Optional. The hook that should have been  used.
* @param string $message     Optional. A message regarding the change.
*/
  function _deprecated_hook( $hook, $version, $replacement = null, $message = null ) {
/**
 * Fires when a deprecated hook is called.
 *
 * @since 4.6.0
 *
 * @param string $hook        The hook that was called.
 * @param string $replacement The hook that should be used as a replacement.
 * @param string $version     The version of WordPress that deprecated the argument used.
 * @param string $message     A message regarding the change.
 */
do_action( 'deprecated_hook_run', $hook, $replacement, $version, $message );

/**
 * Filters whether to trigger deprecated hook errors.
 *
 * @since 4.6.0
 *
 * @param bool $trigger Whether to trigger deprecated hook errors. Requires
 *                      `WP_DEBUG` to be defined true.
 */
if ( WP_DEBUG && apply_filters( 'deprecated_hook_trigger_error', true ) ) {
    $message = empty( $message ) ? '' : ' ' . $message;
    if ( ! is_null( $replacement ) ) {
        /* translators: 1: WordPress hook name, 2: version number, 3: alternative hook name */
        trigger_error( sprintf( __( '%1$s is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version %2$s! Use %3$s instead.' ), $hook, $version, $replacement ) . $message );
    } else {
        /* translators: 1: WordPress hook name, 2: version number */
        trigger_error( sprintf( __( '%1$s is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version %2$s with no alternative available.' ), $hook, $version ) . $message );
    }
}
}
```

Full functions.php: https://pastebin.com/715qwx65

Comment: adding code will be easier to trigger whats the issue

Comment: Added code from pastebin + the codesnippet in question